# Customizing the numbering scheme

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, numbering, lncs, autoref

I'm rather new to TeX and got it working, but letting it look nice is a different can of worms :-)
I'm using [`llncs`](https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines) and [`hyperref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). My numbering scheme at the moment is the default, like

> part: III Experimental...
>   sec: 5 Results...
>   subsec: 5.1 Features...
>   subsub: method foo...

Is it possible to pimp `hyperref` so `\autoref` gives instead

> part: 3 Experimental...
>   sec: 3.5 Results...
>   subsec: 3.5.1 Features...
>   subsub: 3.5.1.1 method foo...

If it is necessary to move down part to section and define a `\subsubsubsection`, that wouldn't hurt. If I need a different package, neither.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: To expand on what CarLaTeX says, can you please give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). That is, we need a latex file, that compiles and is as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. For your question at a minimum we need to know your document class. If you give a include a latex file with your part and section headings, and any relevant packages, that should be enough.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Your question is about the numbering of sectioning headers and not really related to the `hyperref` package.

Since you're using the `llncs` document class, all you need to do is provide the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\thepart.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % to enable showing of subsubsection-level numbers
```

---

A full MWE (with optional use of the cross-referencing capabilities of the `cleveref` package):

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\thepart.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref} % optional

\begin{document}

\setcounter{part}{2}
\part{Experimental \dots}  \label{part:exp}

\setcounter{section}{4}
\section{Results \dots}  \label{sec:results}

\subsection{Features \dots}  \label{sec:features}

\subsubsection{Method foo \dots}  \label{sec:method}
Bla bla bla \dots

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip

\noindent
Crossreferences to \autoref{part:exp} and \autoref{sec:results}, 
\autoref{sec:features} and \autoref{sec:method}.

\noindent
Crossreferences to \cref{part:exp,sec:results,sec:features,sec:method}.
\end{document}
```